# Hide and show ranges according to criteria in a target cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown showing months of the year and I'm trying to hide columns based on the selection.

This is what I have but I can't get it working.  I'm new to this so my knowledge is very limited.

```
Sub Month_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "January": Columns("FF:GD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                             Columns("B:FE,GE:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "February": Columns("GF:HB").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                              Columns("B:GE,HC:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "March": Columns("HD:IF").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                           Columns("B:HC,IG:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "April": Columns("JE:JI").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                           Columns("B:JD,JJ:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "May": Columns("JE:JI").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                         Columns("B:JD,JJ:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "June": Columns("JE:JI").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                          Columns("B:JD,JJ:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "July": Columns("B:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                          Columns("AE:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "August": Columns("AF:BD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                            Columns("B:AE,BE:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "September": Columns("BE:CD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                               Columns("B:BD,CE:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "October": Columns("CE:DD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                             Columns("B:CD,DE:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "November": Columns("DF:ED").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                              Columns("B:DE,EE:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "December": Columns("EE:FE").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                              Columns("B:ED,FF:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: My spreadsheet]

Comment: *"can't get it working"* is not a useful description. What do you mean by that?  What happens, exactly?

Comment: If you're expecting that to run automatically, it should most likely be `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` not `Month_Change`

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re making your task more complicated than it need be.  If I had a similar project, I would do it the following way:

**Named Ranges**

Along `Row1`, highlight the cells that include all the columns for January and in the Name Box type `January`.  Repeat the same for `February`, `March` and so on – up to and including `December`.

**Private Sub**

As per @Rory’s advice, create a `Private Sub` to ‘Automatically’ hide/unhide the appropriate columns by referring to them by Range Name.  The following code will do it for you - as long as you have named the ranges correctly:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo GetOut
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim MyMonth As String

MyMonth = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value  '<-- It looks like your month of choice is in cell A1

If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:XFD1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  '<-- Hide all columns in one step
    ActiveSheet.Range(MyMonth).EntireColumn.Hidden = False   '<-- Unhide the month chosen in A1
End If

GetOut:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```